# second title in table and vertical line

Tags: tables, line

I would like to add two things in my table: 
First, in the left side of the table, the results are posted for Risk aversion c = 0.5. The right side of the table shows results for c = 2. I want to write this next to 'Risk aversion c = 0.5', but don't know how.
Secondly, the vertical left after the alpha is not continued, but breaks two times. Anyone know how to fix these issues?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Unrestricted optimisation, cumulative statistics, 2014 - 2018}
\begin{tabular}{l|l l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l } \hline 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Risk aversion c = 0.5} \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{11}{c}{Portfolio one} \\
 & m & $\sum\Delta w$ & $r_t$ & $v_t$ & $u_t$ & m & $\sum\Delta w$ & $r_t$ & $v_t$ & $u_t$ \\
$\alpha$= 0 & 1.000 & 2199.877 & \textbf{0.0142} & 1.1878 & -0.2827 & 1.000 & 691.225 & \textbf{0.0048} & \textbf{0.9586} & \textbf{-0.9539} \\ 
$\alpha$= 2 & 0.401 & 899.142 & \textbf{0.0098} & 1.1868 & -0.2869 & 0.113 & 89.631 & \textbf{0.0034} & \textbf{0.9744} & \textbf{-0.9710} \\ 
$\alpha$= 5 & 0.080 & 154.177 & \textbf{0.0085} & 1.1973 & -0.2908 & 0.016 & 14.724 & \textbf{0.0020} & \textbf{0.9875} & \textbf{-0.9856}\\ 
$\alpha$= 10 & 0.009 & 14.294 & \textbf{0.0014} & 1.2244 & -0.3047 & 0.005 & 2.239 & \textbf{0.0009} & \textbf{0.9928} & \textbf{-0.9919}\\
 \multicolumn{11}{c}{Portfolio two} \\
  & m & $\sum\Delta w$ & $r_t$ & $v_t$ & $u_t$ & m & $\sum\Delta w$ & $r_t$ & $v_t$ & $u_t$ \\ 
 $\alpha$= 0 & 1.000 & 198.969 & 0.0011 & \textbf{1.1305} & \textbf{-0.2815} & 1.000 & 80.409 & 0.0000 & 1.0877 & -1.0878 \\ 
 $\alpha$= 2 & 0.522 & 108.120 & 0.0009 & \textbf{1.1307} & \textbf{-0.2818} & 0.186 & 21.504 & -0.0000 & 1.0912 & -1.0912\\ 
$\alpha$= 5 & 0.159 & 35.696 & 0.0004 & \textbf{1.1340} & \textbf{-0.2831} & 0.036 & 5.5989 & -0.0005 & 1.0950 & -1.0956\\
$\alpha$= 10 & 0.034 & 7.484 & -0.0007 & \textbf{1.1378} & \textbf{-0.2851} & 0.009 & 1.487 & -0.0008 & 1.0975 & -1.0983 \\
\hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:scenario_three}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As can be seen in the picture: 
1. I would like to have 'risk aversion c = 2' on the right side
2. The vertical line on the left needs to be continued

Comment: of course! One question (I am new (obviously), but how do I make my snippet compilable? I added a picture with comments in red

Comment: Adding your `\documentclass` and the needed packages, see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Start the code with `\documentclss{` and end it with `\end{document}`. Then we can see the used documentclass and used packages relevant to the given issue ...

Comment: Yes, I inserted document class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breaks in the vertical line are caused by the `\multicolumn{11}` commands. If you use `& \multicolumn{10}`instead, the line will be continuous.

In order to add the second 'Risk aversion', you can use a similar `\multicolumn{5}` command as for the first one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage,11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Unrestricted optimisation, cumulative statistics, 2014 - 2018}
\begin{tabular}{l|l l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l } \hline 
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Risk aversion c = 0.5} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Risk aversion c = 2} \\ \hline \hline
& \multicolumn{10}{c}{Portfolio one} \\
 & m & $\sum\Delta w$ & $r_t$ & $v_t$ & $u_t$ & m & $\sum\Delta w$ & $r_t$ & $v_t$ & $u_t$ \\
$\alpha$= 0 & 1.000 & 2199.877 & \textbf{0.0142} & 1.1878 & -0.2827 & 1.000 & 691.225 & \textbf{0.0048} & \textbf{0.9586} & \textbf{-0.9539} \\ 
$\alpha$= 2 & 0.401 & 899.142 & \textbf{0.0098} & 1.1868 & -0.2869 & 0.113 & 89.631 & \textbf{0.0034} & \textbf{0.9744} & \textbf{-0.9710} \\ 
$\alpha$= 5 & 0.080 & 154.177 & \textbf{0.0085} & 1.1973 & -0.2908 & 0.016 & 14.724 & \textbf{0.0020} & \textbf{0.9875} & \textbf{-0.9856}\\ 
$\alpha$= 10 & 0.009 & 14.294 & \textbf{0.0014} & 1.2244 & -0.3047 & 0.005 & 2.239 & \textbf{0.0009} & \textbf{0.9928} & \textbf{-0.9919}\\
& \multicolumn{10}{c}{Portfolio two} \\
  & m & $\sum\Delta w$ & $r_t$ & $v_t$ & $u_t$ & m & $\sum\Delta w$ & $r_t$ & $v_t$ & $u_t$ \\ 
 $\alpha$= 0 & 1.000 & 198.969 & 0.0011 & \textbf{1.1305} & \textbf{-0.2815} & 1.000 & 80.409 & 0.0000 & 1.0877 & -1.0878 \\ 
 $\alpha$= 2 & 0.522 & 108.120 & 0.0009 & \textbf{1.1307} & \textbf{-0.2818} & 0.186 & 21.504 & -0.0000 & 1.0912 & -1.0912\\ 
$\alpha$= 5 & 0.159 & 35.696 & 0.0004 & \textbf{1.1340} & \textbf{-0.2831} & 0.036 & 5.5989 & -0.0005 & 1.0950 & -1.0956\\
$\alpha$= 10 & 0.034 & 7.484 & -0.0007 & \textbf{1.1378} & \textbf{-0.2851} & 0.009 & 1.487 & -0.0008 & 1.0975 & -1.0983 \\
\hline \hline
\end{tabular}


\label{table:scenario_three}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you should keep in mind, that the table will not fit onto the page as it is currently too wide. Also, I personally would rethink the placement of 'Portfolio one'  and 'Portfolie two'  as they might confuse the reader.